# 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'. IdentityUser cannot be referenced in a class library package - ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an IdentityUser class in a class library (package) of a ASP.NET 5 project. 
Inheriting the IdentityUser class fails and referencing the  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework fails too.
What could be the problem here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your config looks correct, you may want to try forcing a package restore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a class library package in an ASP.NET 5 project, the default framework is dotnet as seen in the project.json above.
Change the frameworks property to:

```
 "frameworks": {
     "dnx451": { },
     "dnxcore50": { }
  }
```

It seems that since I am using a beta version of EF7, this will only work at those frameworks. I am not sure though but this works.